# Qt dialog showed from Cocoa app hides main menu bar

Tags: c++, objective-c, qt, cocoa

I try to show Qt dialog from existing Cocoa application on Mac.
I create QApplication before calling the dialog->exec() function.
The problem is when the dialog pops up the Cocoa application main menu bar dissapears for good.

Any ideas ?

Comment: could be anything; might we see some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has similar problem, the answer is to call QCoreApplication::setAttribute with Qt::AA_MacPluginApplication param.